# Ubuntu Vim full screen not really full screen

Tags: ubuntu, vim, vi

I have added this to my .vimrc file:

```
set lines=999 columns=999
```

This doesn't seem to be full screen though. I have changed my background color to grey, but I can still see the purple terminal surrounding vim. This isn't a huge deal, but it is a little annoying to look at. I'm just wondering if there is a way to completely enter full screen mode in vim. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably by using the "full screen" option of your terminal.  E.g., for Gnome Terminal, this is F11 or "Full Screen" in the "View" menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the terminal, you need to use the terminal's menu (something like *View → Full Screen*; pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> might also work) to switch to fullscreen mode. Vim can only control the terminal's dimensions via the `:set lines= columns=` command.

The same applies to GVIM; use the functionality of your window manager to switch to fullscreen mode.

If you're looking for a possibility to do this from inside Vim, the [vim-shell plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3123) provides a `:Fullscreen` command that also supports Linux.